# Gets.chomp not working

Tags: ruby

I am doing the 11th exercise of *Learn Ruby the Hard Way*. I have to get this:

```
How old are you? 35
How tall are you? 6'2"
How much do you weigh? 180lbs
So, you're 35 old, 6'2" tall and 180lbs heavy.
```

by writing this:

```
print "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp()
print "How tall are you? "
height = gets.chomp()
print "How much do you weigh? "
weight = gets.chomp()

puts "So, you're #{age} old, #{height} tall and #{weight} heavy."
```

but I get this:

```
How old are you? 
How tall are you? 
How much do you weigh? 
So, you're  old,  tall and  heavy.
```

That means that `gets.chomp` is not working, and I don't understand anything.

Comment: Where is the method `gets.chomp()`?  That appears to either be returning nothing, or maybe some other issue... ?

Comment: @gravity `Kernel#gets` and `String#chomp` are Ruby core methods.

Comment: @MladenJablanović That was my point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to enter values, not just press enter, when prompted after running the program:

```
# ⇓   prompt ⇓   ⇓⇓ YOUR INPUT!!! 
How old are you? 35
```

*Sidenote*: parentheses after `chomp` are redundant and not ruby idiomatic.